# Run emulator android and docker for windows

Tags: android, docker, android-emulator

I installed Docker for Windows on windows 10.
I work with Android Studio and emulator android but it’s not compatible with Hyper-v

[image]

I have seen this solution
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43134006/how-can-i-run-both-docker-and-android-studio-emulator-on-windows) but I think he use Docker toolbox ....

What 's the best way, the best solution to run both docker for windows and android emulator ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run Docker by creating a VM Linux using VirtualBox (for example ubuntu or centos) and then run docker inside that VM.

For natively running docker in Windows, you will need Hyper-V enabled which is incompatible with regular Android SDK Emulators - and then you will need Microsoft Android Emulator which is way too old / incompatible with newer Android versions.

So, for me, the only solution is do your Docker stuff in a dedicated VM using VirtualBox.

---- UPDATE 2018-07-19 -----

it seems that Google just offered a new version of Emulator that is compatible with Hyper-V. Check https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

Comment: if the answer is fine for you please mark it as answered