# Workaround for Android Studio AVD on windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, hyper-v, haxm

Windows 10 now uses a couple default features, Credential Guard and Device guard, that use Hyper-V, along with the non-default option of Core Isolation. Unfortunately at this time, HAXM refuses to install with anything Hyper-V enabled. x86 images refuse to run without HAXM.

I found an answer that said to use the ARM images but none newer than nougat are available and I'm specifically trying to troubleshoot compatibility with sdk29 or android 10.

Short of sacrificing security for a small bit of usability (disable core isolation, and device&credential guard) and heaven knows Windows is not known for being highly secure in a *non* reduced security state, is  there any workaround for this at the moment?

I'm running Android Studio 3.5.3 on Windows 10 Home x64 build 1909.

Comment: Did you try/have you seen: [How can I run both Docker and Android Studio Emulator on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43134006/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang I'll have to try that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have been resolved in a later Android Studio release.

See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/