# Android Studio Emulator doesn't work on Windows 11

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I recently installed Windows 11 on my computer. On Windows 10 everthing worked fine and I had no problems. But now on Windows 11 my emulator does launch, but theres just kinda like a progress bar and there is always only "waiting for all target devices to come online".
I have a AMD 5600x Cpu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's an example of a question on windows 11 / android emulator that has sufficient detail for someone to assist.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/68373280/2711811 .  Try running emulator from command-line to get additional info.  Here's another example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68836402/2711811

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio Emulator is not working on Windows 11 using WHPX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68373280/android-studio-emulator-is-not-working-on-windows-11-using-whpx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes windows 11 breaks android emulator on some Intel and AMD chips. There is currently no official fix for this yet however there is a fix which involves replacing some of the emulator binary files with patched files, binary files can be downloaded in the link below

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/202188690#comment18