# Android studio emulator always get freeze

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am working on andorid and my emulator is working fine but now whenever I try to run my project my emulator always get freeze I have also added that picture. Any help to resolve this issue?
[image: Android Emulator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Windows 11 right? A lot of people seem to be having issues and there's an issue about it on Google's tracker:

[Android Studio Emulator is not working on Windows 11 using WHPX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68373280/13598222)

[Android Studio Emulator is not working on Windows 11 when WSL2 is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836402/android-studio-emulator-is-not-working-on-windows-11-when-wsl2-is-installed)

If none of that applies (the question shows how to run the emulator from a terminal, so you can see what the output is) then I'd try in this order:

- close the emulator and make sure there are no emulator processes running in Task Manager
- reboot and try again
- do a Cold Boot in the AVD manager (clears the emulator state)
- delete the AVD and create a new one

but given that it's hanging like that partway through initialisation, it might be an issue with the emulator process itself. Some stuff to try anyway

Comment: Thanks! it works

Answer (score 0):

Try delete this emulator and create some  new emulator.